# How to Align Flutter TextFormField HintText?

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

I want to center align `HintText` with "Ara..." by scrolling down a little bit. How can I do that?

Codes:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 45,
  child: TextFormField(
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: 65,
      ),
      isDense: true,
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Color(0xFFD9D9D9), size: 30),
      hintText: "Ara...",
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 184, 184), fontSize: 19, fontFamily: "Inter Regular", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 64, 64, 73),
      filled: true,
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
      ),
    ),
    style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter Regular", fontSize: 19, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 167, 167, 167)),
  ),
),
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contentPadding`

```
SizedBox(
                        height: 45,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                              minWidth: 65,
                            ),
                            isDense: true,
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,
                                color: Color(0xFFD9D9D9), size: 30),
                            hintText: "Ara...",
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 184, 184),
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontFamily: "Inter Regular",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 64, 64, 73),
                            filled: true,
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Inter Regular",
                              fontSize: 19,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 167, 167, 167)),
                        ),
                      ),
```